# Azure Data Factory deployments with improved CI/CD

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I am following the new recommended ci/cd set up for ADF published here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment-improvements

One section that isn't clear to me is if you now need an additional "dev" ADF where the pipeline publishes to.

Under the old model you would do your development work in an ADF linked to git, do a pull request to merge back into the collaboration branch and then click publish. This would publish to the adf_publish branch in the same ADF.

With the new model do you have an ADF linked to git where you do your dev work as before - but does the pipeline deploy to a new separate "dev" ADF (which is not linked to git)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**To answer your question directly:**

No, there is not a separate DEV ADF, The only difference between the Old and New is that you no longer need to manually click publish from your collab branch. The way it works is you now have a build pipleine that is triggered anytime there is an update to your collab branch (via PR), once the build validates and produces the artifact, there is a release pipeline that deploys the ARM template to your DEV Data factory.

Here are screenshots to show:

**1st, Add this package.json file to your collaboration branch**

```
{
    "scripts":{
        "build":"node node_modules/@microsoft/azure-data-factory-utilities/lib/index"
    },
    "dependencies":{
        "@microsoft/azure-data-factory-utilities":"^0.1.5"
    }
}
```

Like I did:

[image: Package.json example]

**2nd, Create the yaml build pipeline and edit the parameters from script below**

```
# Sample YAML file to validate and export an ARM template into a build artifact
# Requires a package.json file located in the target repository

trigger:
- main #collaboration branch

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:

# Installs Node and the npm packages saved in your package.json file in the build

- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'install'
    workingDir: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/<folder-of-the-package.json-file>' #replace with the package.json folder
    verbose: true
  displayName: 'Install npm package'

# Validates all of the Data Factory resources in the repository. You'll get the same validation errors as when "Validate All" is selected.
# Enter the appropriate subscription and name for the source factory.

- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    workingDir: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/<folder-of-the-package.json-file>' #replace with the package.json folder
    customCommand: 'run build validate $(Build.Repository.LocalPath) /subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/testResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/yourFactoryName'
  displayName: 'Validate'

# Validate and then generate the ARM template into the destination folder, which is the same as selecting "Publish" from the UX.
# The ARM template generated isn't published to the live version of the factory. Deployment should be done by using a CI/CD pipeline. 

- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    workingDir: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/<folder-of-the-package.json-file>' #replace with the package.json folder
    customCommand: 'run build export $(Build.Repository.LocalPath) /subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/testResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/yourFactoryName "ArmTemplate"'
  displayName: 'Validate and Generate ARM template'

# Publish the artifact to be used as a source for a release pipeline.

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/<folder-of-the-package.json-file>/ArmTemplate' #replace with the package.json folder
    artifact: 'ArmTemplates'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

This build should run every time there is a change to your collaboration branch.

**3rd, Create the Release Pipeline that will deploy to your DEV ADF using the build artifact (ARM Template and Parameter files)**

[image: Release Pipeline]

TASK DETAILS:

[image: Release Pipeline Task Details]

Do not forget to set up Continuous deployment trigger on the build for ADF.

And that's all there is to it, no more clicking that pesky Publish button, but instead you do have to deal with manually inputting the override parameters... you win some you lose some....

**EDIT:**

I found that there was an issue if you have global parameters included in your ARM Template, if they are specified, when you deploy to your DEV ADF, it will disconnect your factory from Azure DevOps Git. To avoid this you can add Global Parameters via the PostDeploy powershell script.

Here are the steps for doing this:

**1.**
Make sure for Include in ARM Template is unchecked within your Azure Data Factory Global Parameters page:

[image: Global Parameters Uncheck]

You need to save a globalParameters json file in your collaboration Branch for each environment of ADF. This file will be used in the Powershell script to ensure the globalParameter exists in your ADF.

[image: GLobalParameter Json file]

**2.**
Create the Powershell script file and save it in your Collaboration Branch so it can be used in the release via an Az Powershell Task.

```
param
(
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [String] $globalParametersFilePath,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [String] $resourceGroupName,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [String] $dataFactoryName
)

Import-Module Az.DataFactory

$newGlobalParameters = New-Object 'system.collections.generic.dictionary[string,Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory.Models.GlobalParameterSpecification]'

Write-Host "Getting global parameters JSON from: " $globalParametersFilePath
$globalParametersJson = Get-Content $globalParametersFilePath

Write-Host "Parsing JSON..."
$globalParametersObject = [Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject]::Parse($globalParametersJson)

foreach ($gp in $globalParametersObject.GetEnumerator()) {
    Write-Host "Adding global parameter:" $gp.Key
    $globalParameterValue = $gp.Value.ToObject([Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory.Models.GlobalParameterSpecification])
    $newGlobalParameters.Add($gp.Key, $globalParameterValue)
}

$dataFactory = Get-AzDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $dataFactoryName
$dataFactory.GlobalParameters = $newGlobalParameters

Write-Host "Updating" $newGlobalParameters.Count "global parameters."

Set-AzDataFactoryV2 -InputObject $dataFactory -Force
```

**3.**
Make sure there is a Az Powershell Task in your Release pipeline to run the PostDeployment powershell script with given parameters.

[image: Az Powershell task Configuration]

If all of this is set up correctly then you should have a completely automated CI/CD process built for ADF (and it shouldn't disconnect you from Git)

Let me know if I can be of any other help!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. What you're describing is how I currently have things setup - essentially what is outlined here as "Current CI/CD workflow": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment-improvements#current-cicd-flow. I'm looking at implementing "The new CI/CD workflow" outlined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment-improvements#the-new-cicd-flow. This new CI/CD flow removes the need to manually click the "Publish" button and publishes to Dev from within a pipeline.

Comment: Oh I see, apologies I misunderstood. That is pretty cool though, I know I had seen something about auto publish out there. It looks like the only difference is there can now be an automated build task that will generate the ADF Artifact (rather than having a Azure DevOps Repo artifact) then this can trigger release to DEV ADF upon new build being available. So in fact it is completely automated CI/CD process. That's awesome, and allows you to deploy to every environment in the same manner. Thank you, you are helping me learn.

Comment: I will edit my answer to reflect, and also give examples when I implement this new solution.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to try this out and update your original answer. I've just given this a go and it's not working as I would expect. Let me outline my steps...I have my ADF_DEV factory linked to git. I create a feature branch on there and make some edits. I now do a pull request back to my main branch. This kicks of my build pipeline. That build pipeline validates and builds the ARM files. I then use the ARM files in my deployment. I deploy the ARM templates onto ADF_DEV factory. When I open ADF_DEV it has been updated. But now it is not connected to git. That can't be right.

Comment: I figured out the issue was because we (probably) both had Global Parameters included in our ARM templates, I have updated my answer to automate the globalParameter creation via Az Powershell, it's quite simple. And I now have a fully automated CI/CD process for our EDW ADF. Thank you!

Comment: Please Accept as answer and vote up if it helps with your issue!

Comment: You're right I did have global parameters. However after the last update you made I initially used your global parameters powershell code to push the global parameters to dev as well as my other environments. When I did that the ADF got disconnected from git again. If I create the global parameters as normal in dev (but without ticking the Include in ARM box) and use the powershell to create them only in other environments then it works and dev remains linked to git. Does that sound right?

Comment: Yes it does, you don't have to remove them from Data Factory, just uncheck the include in ARM Template option. Cheers!

Comment: I've set up the new CI/CD process and it works great. Then I thought I would include global parameters and whammo it won't validate any more. I'm getting kinda tired of these half baked features that don't work properly

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Theoretically in your automated build pipeline you could have a download task that will download your ARM template artifact, so that it is available not just at run time, and instead link to that... I haven't implemented that yet (too busy with 5,000 projects) but in my head sounds feasible and not terribly difficult, especially given that it can probably just be part of the automated build. If you come up with something please let me know!

Comment: Specifically the issue is that for some reason the global parameter json definition is not saved into the Collabaration branch, but the pipeline references to it _are_ saved, so the validation step fails due to missing references. The global parameter json _is_ saved into the adf_publish branch, but as per the new CI/CD guide we are no longer using that branch. I think you're suggesting that I add a step in my build to gather the global parameter json from adf_publish, but I would rather the feature just actually worked consistently.

Comment: Also, I don't want to pursue any further because this makes me nervous: _when you deploy to your DEV ADF, it will disconnect your factory from Azure DevOps Git._ it really seems like this is half baked (also I notice you can't reference global parameters in parameterised linked services so they really have limited use for me)

Comment: For the global parameters just use power shell like the documentation says. That’s what we do. And as far as your comment about not being able to use global parameters in parameterized linked services, I think that’s incorrect. I have used global parameters for linked services, datasets, and activities. Also, in my scenario I was referring to, adf_publish literally doesn’t exist, so you wouldn’t be copying anything from there. I thought you were referring to the fact that on the release pipeline it no longer automatically populates all of your over ride parameters.

Comment: I was just saying if we wanted the parameters to auto populate, like they used to. An alternative would be to have the arm templates copied to the main branch at build time. Therefore they are always available, and not just at runtime.

Comment: I rechecked and you can't use global parameters as an expression directly in a linked service definition. You _can_ use them in a pipleine and pass them down to a parameterised linked service. Which means if I have one linked service and ten pipelines I need to duplicate this reference in ten pipelines. Anyway I appreciate your detailed answer above, I just wanted to air my disatisfaction about this feature.