# Selective releases in Azure Data Factory and DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

We have 2 Data factories (dev and prd) with an Azure DevOps Git integration. All setup for CI/CD as mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment:

- Development in different features branches
- Different features to master branch by pull requests
- Publish to adf_publish branch
- Azure pipeline to release from ADF-dev to ADF-prd

An additional requirement we would like to add, is the possibity to perform selective releases to our prd Data Factory. F.e.: New development A was published to our adf_publish branch and the validation of new development A is still in progress. Meanwhile, new request B needs to be released to ADF-prd as soon as possible (not as a hotfix). However, this is currently blocked by development A, which still has to be validated. So we would like to have the possibility to only release request B to our adf-prd and exclude development A from that release (as it's not validated yet).

Unfortunately, this feature is not supported in Data Factory itself (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment). We are looking for a solution in Azure DevOps, but so far without luck. Does anyone has a solution for this?

Thanks in advance,
Kind regards,
Jef

Answer (score 1):

There is now a way to create an ADF build artifact from a branch and using that artifact to deploy to upper environments, rather than manually clicking Publish in the ADF UX. Using this feature, you could have a breakdown of branches like so:

**feature branches** (for devlopment)

**develop branch** (for things not validated yet)

**main branch** (for things validated or that need to be published to your physical ADF)

using this architecture you could develop a pipeline in feature branch, push it to develop branch where it could have an automated CI build pipeline that generates artifacts, this could either be deployed to a DEV ADF or just used as a validation step, once things are validated in your develop branch, you can do a PR to your main branch which deploys to your DEV or TEST ADF.

In this example, your New Development A would be sitting in the develop branch while your new request B would be pushed directly to your main branch and that would trigger an automated build and deployment to whatever ADF you want...

Please see this StackOverflow Post that I answered on already, it is very thorough.

[Azure Data Factory deployments with improved CI/CD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68374531/azure-data-factory-deployments-with-improved-ci-cd/68385012#68385012)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is the CI/CD behavior for ADF. Since there is no selective publish, until this moment, there is no way to achieve this using a different branching model and also supported by Microsoft.
The way I found to deal with those parallel developments is make use of feature flags (global parameters + if conditions inside pipelines). This is the Microsoft recommended solution, which I don't see as a solution, but a "workaround" for something that they haven't figure out yet.

The other option is having an ADF for each development squad and treat every sprint as a release. This will probably avoid concurrency to promote release to QA and Production.

Hope it helps.